# xcode : adding external framework

Tags: frameworks, libraries

I have a .framework (external framework) file that was created by xcode 9.2 with deployment target 9.0. I wanted to link this framework with my project. I linked the framework in embeded binaries and frameworks and libraries. There was no error with that but my application not being opened.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a duplicate appdelegate in the given external framework. SO that when we add it to the current project, Appdelegate of the current project not called.

So make sure the external framework not having duplicate Appdelegate.
Thanks